# Alternatives to the --sysroot switch of gcc?

Tags: gcc, path, header

The `--sysroot` switch is useful when you don't want the headers/libraries in the standard paths affect your build.

> `--sysroot=dir`: Use dir as the logical root directory for headers and
>   libraries. For example, if the
>   compiler would normally search for
>   headers in /usr/include and libraries
>   in /usr/lib, it will instead search
>   dir/usr/include and dir/usr/lib. [[ref]](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Can the same thing be accomplished through the use of environment variables, the *gcc specs* file, or any other methods that do not require command line switches?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can use environment variables you can add --sysroot to CFLAGS.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper script around gcc that executes the actual gcc with the flags you wish. This works with Makefiles and complex builds that mess with environment variables. You only need to make sure your gcc script is earlier in the PATH than the actual gcc binary. The script itself is just two lines,

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/gcc --sysroot=/your/sysroot "$@"
```

and if `$HOME/bin` is early in your PATH, you can put the script in `$HOME/bin`, and it will not affect any other users.

If you have a `configure` script that expressly looks for `gcc` in `/usr/bin/`, you may need to rename `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc.bin`, and name your script `/usr/bin/gcc`. This will affect all users. If you need this, but also want it to affect only certain user or users, use

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$(id -un)" -eq "theuser" ] && exec /usr/bin/gcc.bin --sysroot=/your/sysroot "$@"
exec /usr/bin/gcc.bin "$@"
```

You can do variants, e.g. specific user accounts or group memberships to set a specific sysroot, using the same scheme.

Comment: This is the only solution when I tried to cross-compile AXIS2/C. For some mysterious reasons, the makefile of AXIS2/C just stripped the "--sysroot" options I put in CFLAGS, LDFLAGS and LIBS environment variable when linking the sharedlib. I had also tried to disable shared with ./configure --disable-shared option, but the linker will complain "duplicated symbol" bug during the final linking stage.

Comment: @RichardLiu: If you run `util/autogen.sh` for AXIS2/C 1.6.0, it grows a new `--with-sysroot=DIR` configure option. It looks like its only passed to libtool, however. Adding `--with-cflags-sysroot` configure option (about 30 lines in each `configure.ac`) seems to work. Do you want to try that patch? The entire project seems stale, as it fails on the first file it tries to compile (`util/src/platforms/unix/uuid_gen_unix.c`) on my dev machine..