# gcc: specify sysroot as environment variable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, environment-variables

This is exactly the same question as this: [Alternatives to the --sysroot switch of gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977182/alternatives-to-the-sysroot-switch-of-gcc) but it has a very vague non-constructive answer.

So I just migrated toolchains and I would not like to replace every instance of 'gcc' with 'gcc --sysroot=/my/path/'. I've already tried to put /my/path in $PATH, $SYSROOT and $GNUSYSROOT.

gcc -dumpspecs has only 4 references to sysroot:

```
*sysroot_spec:
--sysroot=%R

*sysroot_suffix_spec:


*sysroot_hdrs_suffix_spec:
```

Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: If it is the same question, opening an identical one isn't very productive.

Comment: I added another solution in the other question, one that relies on a wrapper script. It may be easier with projects that mess with environment variables on their own. It also works with any gcc options.