# PPC cross-compile and Fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

```
OS: CentOS 7 x86_64
```

I am working on a C (later ADA) cross-compiler from `x86_64` to `PowerPC32`. `CentOS 7` has a cross-compiler already built in its default repository, so through `yum`, I ran

```
yum install gcc-powerpc64-linux-gnu.x86_64
```

Although this is a `ppc64` compiler, I can pass a flag to force `32-bit` mode so for now, that does not worry me. I just want to get it compiling even in 64-bit mode.

---

I am trying to compile the following hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     printf("Hello, World!");
     return 0;
 }
```

When I ran this with regular `gcc`, it compiles and runs just fine. The problem is that when compiling I get the error mentioned above.

Here is the **output of the compilation command**

```
[root@dev cross-compil-tests]# powerpc64-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=powerpc64-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: powerpc64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.5-20150702/configure --bindir=/usr/bin --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --datadir=/usr/share --disable-decimal-float --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-gold --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-nls --disable-plugin --disable-shared --disable-silent-rules --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-threads --enable-checking= --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-initfini-array --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-linker-build-id --enable-nls --enable-obsolete --enable-targets=all --exec-prefix=/usr --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --includedir=/usr/include --infodir=/usr/share/info --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --prefix=/usr --program-prefix=powerpc64-linux-gnu- --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --sysconfdir=/etc --target=powerpc64-linux-gnu --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/ --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-newlib --with-sysroot=/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/sys-root --with-system-libunwind --with-system-zlib --without-headers --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/cloog-install --with-cpu-32=power4 --with-tune-32=power6 --with-cpu-64=power4 --with-tune-64=power6 --enable-secureplt --with-long-double-128
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'hello' '-v' '-mtune=power6' '-mcpu=power4'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/cc1 -quiet -v -D__unix__ -D__gnu_linux__ -D__linux__ -Dunix -D__unix -Dlinux -D__linux -Asystem=linux -Asystem=unix -Asystem=posix hello.c -msecure-plt -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -mtune=power6 -mcpu=power4 -auxbase hello -version -o /tmp/ccwki2NC.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (powerpc64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../powerpc64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:  
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (powerpc64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 0af58e346ee6cfd1f5beece8a365542e
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

**These lines are of interest to me**

```
[...]
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../powerpc64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/include"
[...]
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
```

The **ignoring nonexistent directory** entries might be the problem. I do not know how to fix it, and have removed/reinstalled the cross-compiler multiple times. I also cannot find a C library for the cross-compiler that I can download so that I can link it manually with the `-I` flag.

---

**Attempted Solutions**

I did a:

```
find stdio.h | grep stdio.h
```

and linked the directory of where I found it using `-I`. New error, could not find `stubs-32.h`... Well ok, fixed that through some more googling (simple yum install) and then I got `crt1.o` not found... etc. Frustrating, but I believe this was not the correct direction to go anyways.

here is the ones my computer found

```
[root@lxdev-gab gnu]# find "stdio.h" / | grep "stdio.h"
find: ‘stdio.h’: No such file or directory
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/share/man/man0p/stdio.h.0p.gz
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your cross-compile you should add a `-sysroot` to tell GCC where to find the headers and libraries for the power machine. Also see [What is a sysroot exactly and how do I create one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39920712/608639) and [Alternatives to the --sysroot switch of gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2977182/608639)

Comment: @jww correct, but regardless I cannot find the header/library files anywhere. I updated my question at the end showing what/where "stdio.h" files are in my computer. As you can see, none for ppc have installed (usr/include/ wont work because its for diff architecture). Do you know how I could obtain the standard c lib for ppc?

Comment: @jww Unfortunately this is not for a regular computer, but for a micro-controller (not sure if thats the right word, its a custom card built specifically for this project). Thank you for the gesture though! What do you mean work bare metal? And thats what I cannot figure out: where do I find the libs so that I can install them?

Comment: If CentOS is anything like Fedora then they don't do userland cross-compiles. Fedora does not even supply a userland cross-compiler for ARM. The only thing Fedora provides is a cross-compiler for ARM kernels. Your mileage may vary on CentOS. Also see [Searching for Packages with yum](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-searching-packages.html) in the manual.